# ¿Cómo generar espacios verticales entre botones en Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" style="width: 58rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"> se dieron ciberataques que borran datos de bancos y el Gobierno</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">24/2/2022</h6>
    <div class="container-all">

      <p class=""> aca va un articulo que cree</p>
      <img src="img/mujer hacker.jpg" alt="Mujer hacker">
    </div>
    <p class="saltos"></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right ">Aceptar publicación</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right">Rechazar publicación</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Que quieres hacer?  ¿Separar los botones entre sí? ¿O separar los botones del "Mujer hacker"?

Comment: los botones entre si

Comment: La próxima vez, no agregues ruido a la pregunta. En su lugar, _describe el problema_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para la separación de elementos bootstrap usa las clases de [utilidades de espaciado](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/), entre las cuales seguramente te interese, por ejemplo, esta *ms-2*, que quiere decir lo siguiente:

- **m**:  margen a aplicar
- **s**:  en bootstrap 5 significa *start*, en bootstrap 4 y anteriores se usa **l** que significa *izquierda* (left)
- **x**: donde **x** representa un número, entre el 0 y el 5, al cual se le aplica una fórmula que encontraras en el enlace que he puesto antes, y que tiene en cuenta el espaciado actual establecido.

Por lo tanto, **ms-2** significa:

> margen izquierdo con separación de 2

Ejemplo (he puesto un ms-5 para que lo veas mejor en el segundo botón):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" style="width: 58rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"> se dieron ciberataques que borran datos de bancos y el Gobierno</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">24/2/2022</h6>
    <div class="container-all">

      <p class=""> aca va un articulo que cree</p>
      <img src="img/mujer hacker.jpg" alt="Mujer hacker">
    </div>
    <p class="saltos"></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right ">Aceptar publicación</button>
    <button type="button" class="ms-5 btn btn-danger float-right">Rechazar publicación</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias , muy buena explicación

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te haya servido. Si esta respuesta cumplimenta tu pregunta no olvides marcala como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente para siempre, gracias. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) explican como aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo cuando son válidas.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Importante aclarar que esta clase para agregar márgenes es de forma horizontal, y no vertical como indica el título de la pregunta, seguramente error del OP. En ese caso la clase sería `my-*`.